# django postgres psycopg2 database not found

Tags: python, django, git, postgresql, psycopg2

On my accounting project.. i have database in postgresql.
I has to change model of my project. After changing and appylying migrations for several times i got my database structure very bad. And was unable to appy any futher migrations being my models.py all correct.

So i deleted my database named 'goms'. Deleted my git repo. And agained cloned a working 'develop' branch. After running

```
./manage.py makemigratins
```

i get

```
File "/home/student/work02/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "goms" does not exist
```

I belive the database must be created itself when making and applying migration.
It seems psycopg has some cache stored which is searching goms instead of creating one.
Plz help m stuck.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to *create your database before applying the migrations*.

If you would follow the official Django tutorial, you may see a note in a [`Database Setup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) section:

> If you’re using PostgreSQL or MySQL, make sure you’ve created a
>   database by this point. Do that with “CREATE DATABASE database_name;”
>   within your database’s interactive prompt.

Comment: ok i have create ddatabase again. It has no any relations. But now when i try to make migration.. it is looking for previous fields. saying....django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "core_fiscalyear" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e_fiscalyear"."id", "core_fiscalyear"."year" FROM "core_fisc...